# How to mount Windows 2008 shared folder on SHMZ 6.6 (CentOS) client?

Tags: linux, centos, windows-server-2008, server-message-block, freepbx

We have a Windows Server 2008 with a shared folder. It is needed to mount this shared folder in SHMZ 6.6 Linux (FreePBX, CentOS).

I tried the "Even-better method" from https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares - didn't work: when I try to cd to mounted folder - terminal freezes.

Tried mount.cifs - freezes right after the command is executed.

Tried connecting using smbclient - successfully connects, I am able to browse subfolders.

Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `sec=ntlm,servern=SERVERNAME` to mount options worked!